# Fraps with long gaps in recording

Tags: java, video-capture, opengl

We are using Fraps to record a Java openGL (JOGL) application.
Usually at 1280x720.  The recorded video has very long gaps/freezes (well over a second sometimes).  Even using much smaller resolution and limiting Fraps frame rate to 20 does not seem to help.  The audio stream is perfect, but the video stream is not.

We've tried getting rid of other processes.  It works better when our application is not using too much cpu, but still not good.  Any suggestions?

Thanks, Stephen

Fraps 3.2.3

Vista Home Premium 32 bit (up to date with service packs)

NVidia 8600GT, driver 257.21

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be a bug that has been fixed in the latest version of Fraps.

The authors were helpful in diagnosing and fixing this issue after correspondence with them.